# CSS3 animations only behaving correctly for CHROME & FIREFOX (Not responding in OPERA?)

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, opera, css-transitions

Language: **CSS3** / **jQuery** / **HTML5** / **PHP**

What I have here are a bunch of **round HREFs styled like DIVs** on an HTML5 page.

[image]

On pageload, they are supposed to scale up from **0%** of their actual size to **0.80%**,
... and on hover, they are supposed to scale up to **100%** (This is all done using CSS3).

**LIVE DEMO:** `http://174.127.117.20/~interact/`
(If you view this on CHROME, you will see it behaving correctly as it should.)

**The DILEMMA:**

- However, if you view it using the **OPERA** browser, it does not animate
  (scale up) on pageload at all.

I have 10 bubbles in all. These bubbles are classed in this order `class="expand update1"` (`update1` to `update10`).
Initially, on pageload I show them using jQuery with delays:

```js
// LOAD BUBBLES

    $('.update1').delay(300).show(0);
    $('.update2').delay(1000).show(0);
    $('.update3').delay(500).show(0);
    $('.update4').delay(100).show(0);
    $('.update5').delay(250).show(0);
    $('.update6').delay(800).show(0);
    $('.update7').delay(500).show(0);
    $('.update8').delay(200).show(0);
    $('.update9').delay(600).show(0);
    $('.update10').delay(150).show(0);
```

**Then using CSS3 animations, I have them scale up from 0% to 0.80% of their size:**
(I have it done this way to make sure that I have everything in. Perhaps I could be doing it wrong, or just being plain lazy... But I don't think the problem lies here?)

```css
@keyframes anim
{
0% {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
100% {
        transform: scale(0.80);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.80);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.80);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.80);}
}

@-moz-keyframes anim /* FIREFOX */
{
0% {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
100% {
        transform: scale(0.80);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.80);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.80);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.80);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim /* SAFARI and CHROME */
{
0% {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
100% {
        transform: scale(0.80);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.80);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.80);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.80);}
}

@-o-keyframes anim /* OPERA */
{
0% {
        transform: scale(0,0);
        -ms-transform: scale(0,0);
        -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); }
100% {
        transform: scale(0.80);
        -ms-transform: scale(0.80);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.80);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.80);}
}
```

And here is the complete CSS for these bubbles:

```css
a.expand{
    display: none;
    margin: auto;

    transition:all .8s; 

    /* FIREFOX */
    -moz-transition:all .8s;

    /* SAFARI and CHROME */
    -webkit-transition:all .8s;

    /* OPERA */
    -o-transition:all .8s;

    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0px;

    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 0, 10s;

    transform: scale(0.80);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.80);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.80);
    -o-transform: scale(0.80);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.80);
}

a.expand:hover{
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
}


.update1 {
    animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update2 {
    animation: anim 1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 1s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update3 {
    animation: anim 1.2s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1.2s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 1.2s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 1.2s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 1.2s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update4 {
    animation: anim 1.1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1.1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 1.1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 1.1s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 1.1s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update5 {
    animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update6 {
    animation: anim 0.8s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 0.8s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 0.8s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 0.8s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 0.8s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update7 {
    animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update8 {
    animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 0.9s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update9 {
    animation: anim 1.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 1.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 1.9s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 1.9s 1 ease-in-out;
}
.update10 {
    animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: anim 1.4s 1 ease-in-out;
}

.update1, .update5, .update9 {
    background-color: #174EF2;
}

.update2, .update6, .update10 {
    background-color: #F13137;
}

.update3, .update7 {
    background-color: #FEB514;
}

.update4, .update8 {
    background-color: #04AA17;
}
```

I don't really know why I am not able to target the **Opera browser**? I can't tell what I'm missing anymore, any guidance & help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

---

I am using the latest version of Opera: **Version 12.11**, **build 1661**

Comment: What version of Opera?  They are only supported in the very latest versions. http://caniuse.com/css-animation

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I am using the **latest version** of Opera: **Version 12.11, build 1661**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bL9y7/ - something similar but without animation/scale, only with transition/font-size, works in Opera 12.11 even without vendor prefixes

Comment: Thanks for the response @Victor, but my problem with Opera is the preload animation (when the browser loads, they are supposed to expand to their actual size), I do not have a problem with the scaling/font-size or transitioning.

Comment: Im my example they also are expanded from zero to the actual size when browser loads, but without animation. P.S. Would you like to create jsfiddle to play with?

Comment: Why you use vendor-prefixed property in keyframes for different vendor (e.g. `-ms-transform` in `@-o-keyframes anim`)? Also order of prefixed and non-prefixed properties may be significant: http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2012/08/10/css-vendor-prefixes-in-opera-12-50-snapshots

Answer (score -2):

You are using

```
 -webkit-animation: for chrome
 -moz-animation: for mozilla
 -o-animation: for opera
```

I think in opera the css3 is not properly rendering. Try going through w3school and check the compatibility of css3 in different browsers.

Comment: This is not an answer. Also if you want to check CSS support use http://caniuse.com. w3schools is the last place you want to be looking for reference material.

Comment: seems you have not used w3schools. the live editor provided by them is very good and easy way to test cross browser compatibility

Comment: I have used w3schools. If you want a live editor there are many options that are much better including http://jsfiddle.net. As for why w3schools is not a good resource, see http://w3fools.com/.

Comment: I am using jsfiddle.net, but in that you do not get list commands and the respective details as shown in w3school. May be they have some issues, but simplicity is what matters

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the CSS3 is not properly rendering for Opera browsers, thus my above post. However, your post is not an answer, it is simply a repetition of the original post (which is a question). I have tried everything for cross-browser compatibility, I have posted my question as a last resort. I can't figure out what I'm missing (from my view-point I have everything covered), thus I need further assistance from someone with a keener eye. Thanks for your time.